# I am using pdf viewer taking files from asset but my app becomes very slow.is there any solution?

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-viewer

Pdf viewer works fine when pdf file size is small but in my case pdf files are large (almost 350+ Mb ).So it takes long time to open file.I am also facing another problem occur when switch to landscape from portrait. Please guide me is there any best solution for pdf viewer.Please don't make it duplicate because there is no suitable solution for my problem.

**Quran.java**

```
public class Quran extends Fragment {
    PDFView pdfView;
    String openParah;

    public Quran(String parah) {
        if (parah.equals("1")){
            openParah="parah1.pdf";
        }
        else if (parah.equals("2")){
            openParah="parah2.pdf";
        }
        else if (parah.equals("3")){
            openParah="parah3.pdf";
        }
        else if (parah.equals("4")){
            openParah="parah4.pdf";
        }
        else if (parah.equals("5")){
            openParah="parah5.pdf";
        }
        else if (parah.equals("6")){
            openParah="parah6.pdf";
        }
        else if (parah.equals("7")){
            openParah="parah7.pdf";
        }
        else if (parah.equals("8")){
            openParah="parah8.pdf";
        }
        else if (parah.equals("9")){
            openParah="parah9.pdf";
        }
        else if (parah.equals("10")){
            openParah="parah10.pdf";
        }
        else if (parah.equals("11")){
            openParah="parah11.pdf";
        }
        else if (parah.equals("12")){
            openParah="parah12.pdf";
        }
        else if (parah.equals("13")){
            openParah="parah13.pdf";
        }
        else if (parah.equals("14")){
            openParah="parah14.pdf";
        }
        else if (parah.equals("15")){
            openParah="parah15.pdf";
        }
        else if (parah.equals("16")){
            openParah="parah16.pdf";
        }
        else if (parah.equals("17")){
            openParah="parah17.pdf";
        }
        else if (parah.equals("18")){
            openParah="parah18.pdf";
        }
        else if (parah.equals("19")){
            openParah="parah19.pdf";
        }
        else if (parah.equals("20")){
            openParah="parah20.pdf";
        }
        else if (parah.equals("21")){
            openParah="parah21.pdf";
        }
        else if (parah.equals("22")){
            openParah="parah22.pdf";
        }
        else if (parah.equals("23")){
            openParah="parah23.pdf";
        }
        else if (parah.equals("24")){
            openParah="parah24.pdf";
        }
        else if (parah.equals("25")){
            openParah="parah25.pdf";
        }
        else if (parah.equals("26")){
            openParah="parah26.pdf";
        }
        else if (parah.equals("27")){
            openParah="parah27.pdf";
        }
        else if (parah.equals("28")){
            openParah="parah28.pdf";
        }
        else if (parah.equals("29")){
            openParah="parah29.pdf";
        }
        else if (parah.equals("30")){
            openParah="parah30.pdf";
        }
    }
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_quran, null);

        pdfView = (PDFView) view.findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
        pdfView.fromAsset(openParah)
                .enableSwipe(true)
                .swipeHorizontal(false)
                .enableDoubletap(true)
                .defaultPage(0)
                .enableAnnotationRendering(false)
                .password(null)
                .scrollHandle(null)

                .load();
        return view;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: "I am also facing another problem occur when switch to landscape from portrait" -- unless you say what the problem is, nobody can help you. "So it takes long time to open file" -- use smaller files.

Comment: Qusstion is that is there any alternate solution because i m bound to use large files.

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/01/04/options-viewing-pdfs.html

Comment: For comparison, the PDF specification at 756 pages is only 8.57MB.  A 350MB document is about 40 times larger.  While 350MB is only medium-sized in the context of large PDF files, it would seriously strain the resources of a typical android device. I suspect your documents could be slimmed down through PDF Optimization without too much degradation of the viewing experience.